# xpath select parent elem w/ blank text() after excluding certain children

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to select all div.to_get whose children have no text content, excluding certain elements

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="to_get">
        <span>   </span>
        <span class="exclude">  text is ignored </span>
        <span>   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="to_get">
        <span>  there is text here, so don't select the parent div </span>
        <span class="exclude">  text is ignored </span>
        <span>   </span>
    </div>
    <div class="to_get">
        <span>   </span>
        <span class="exclude">  text is ignored </span>
        <span>  there is text here, so don't select the parent div </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

xpath attempt:

```
//*/body/div[@class='to_get']/descendant::text()[not(ancestor::span/@class='exclude')][normalize-space(.)='']/ancestor::div[@class='to_get']
```

The problem is that this still returns the 2nd (and 3rd) div.to_get because of its 3rd (and 1st) span child. But those divs should be excluded due to its 1st (and 3rd) span child.

The xpath should only select the 1st div.to_get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way (formatted for readability) :

```
//div[
    @class='to_get' 
        and 
    not(
        span[not(@class='exclude') and normalize-space()]
    )
]
```

To compare with the other answer, `not(normalize-space(text())='')` only tests if the first text node in the `<span>` is empty while `normalize-space()` tests if all text node(s) in the `<span>` is empty. Consider the following example that will pass the former but not the latter :

```
<div class="to_get">
    <span>   </span>
    <span class="exclude">  text is ignored </span>
    <span>  <br/> there is text here, so don't select the parent div </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following XPath

```
//div[@class='to_get' and normalize-space(span[not(@class='exclude')]/text())='']
```

selects all `div` with the class `to_get` that only contains empty `span` elements, excluding the `span` elements with the class `exclude`. For the input HTML, this returns only the first `div`.

**Update:**  As noticed as comment, above XPath only checks for the first span. Following XPath

```
//div[@class='to_get'][not(span[not(@class='exclude') and not(normalize-space(text())='')])]
```

selects all `div` elements with the class `to_get` that only contain empty `span` elements excluding the ones having the class `exclude`. For the updated input HTML only the first `div` is returned.

Comment: I unreleased this as the answer because this xpath only looks at the 1st span child.  I've updated the question's html

Comment: @user2426679 Thanks for the info and sorry about that, thought I already checked for different positions of empty `span` elements. I've just updated my answer with a different approach.